# Disable typescript in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I disable TypeScript in VS code. Even though I have installed any plugins for TypeScript, I still get TypeScript warning messages in my Javascript. I referenced the [MS VS Code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript), but it doesn't specify disabling TypeScript.

Comment: The reason you are getting **Typescript Warning** is because **VS Code** detects the `.ts` file and provides **Syntax Highlighting** and **Warnings**, It is not coming from any plugin unless it is **lint** related errors. Otherwise, Whats the point of using code editor?

Comment: But I don't have a .ts file in my project.

Comment: Then in which file you are getting such an error? and what kind of errors? Your question is clear enough.

Comment: VSC uses the TS Language Server for JavaScript